# How to avoid widget/layout overlapping in kivy / python

Tags: python, image, layout, kivy, scrollview

I am facing following issues in Kivy code :

1. spacing between child layouts does not change if the size of window changes.
2. Image appears partially.
3. Image does not scroll horizontally.
4. The widget displays after image overlaps on the image.

I have tried changing the code multiple times but nothing worked.

Kivy code:

```
MyLayout: 
    do_default_tab: False

    size_hint: 1, 1
    padding: 10
    tab_pos: 'top_left'
    
    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab1
        text: "Nifty 50"
        
        GridLayout:
            id:t1bl1
            #orientation: 'vertical'
            width: self.width
            #height:self.width
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols:1
                                    
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_x:False
                do_scroll_y: True
                size_hint_y:0.9
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "y":0.11}
                
                
                GridLayout:
                    id:tmain
                    size:(0.9, root.height)  
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    cols:1
        
                    GridLayout:
                        id:t1bl1
                        #orientation: 'vertical'
                        #padding: 10
                        spacing:10
                        width: self.width
                        #height:self.width
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        cols:1
                                    
                        Label:
                            id:t1heading
                            font_size:12##((self.height/7)*.99 *(self.width/100)*.25)
                            bold:True
                            multiline: False
                            text: 'NIFTY 50 STRATEGY RETURNS'
                            size: self.texture_size
                            #pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.8}
                            size_hint_y: None
                            border:(10,10,10,10)
                        
       #                 ProgressBar:
        #                    id:pbar
         #                   value:0
          #                  min:0
           #                 max:100
            #                #pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.6}
             #               size_hint_x:.8
              #              size_hint_y: None  
                        
        #                Label:
        #                    id:progl
         #                  font_size:12##((self.height/7)*.99 *(self.width/100)*.25)
          #                 bold:False
           #                multiline: False
            #               text: ''
             #              size: self.texture_size
              #             #pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.8}
               #            height:self.texture_size[0]
                #           border:(10,10,10,10)
                            
                    GridLayout:
                        cols:2
                        id:t1bl1_1
                        #orientation:'vertical'
                        background_color:[0, 0, 1, 1]
                        width: self.width
                            #height:self.width
                        size_hint_y: None
                            #height: self.minimum_height
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lbl
                            font_size: 10
                            multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lb2
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lb3
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lb4
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lb5
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl1_1lb6
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                        
                    ScrollView:
                        id:innerscroll
                        do_scroll_x:True
                        do_scroll_y: False
                        GridLayout:
                            id:t1img
                            #orientation: 'vertical'
                            rows:1  
                            size_hint_y:None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            #size: self.minimum_size
                            #size: self.size
                                    
                            Image:
                                id:img1
                                source:'plot.png'
                                #size_hint:(None,None)
                                width: root.width
                                #height:root.width
                                size: self.size
                                
                            Image:
                                id:img1
                                source:'plot.png'
                                size_hint:(None,None)
                                width: root.width
                                #height:root.width
                                size: self.texture_size
                                
                    GridLayout:
                        id:t1subhead
                        cols:1
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1heading2
                            font_size:12##((self.height/7)*.99 *(self.width/100)*.25)
                            bold:True
                            multiline: False
                            text: 'MODEL PORTFOLIO FOR THE MONTH'
                            size: self.texture_size
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
                            height:self.texture_size[0]
                                
                    GridLayout:
                        cols:2
                        id:t1bl2_SubH1
                        width: self.width
                        #height:self.width*.5
                        size_hint_y: None
                        #height: self.minimum_height
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb1
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                        
                                    
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb2
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb3
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb4
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb5
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb6
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb7
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb8
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                            
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb9
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size
                                
                        Label:
                            id:t1bl2_1lb10
                            font_size: 10
                            # multiline: True
                            text: ''
                            size: self.texture_size

                                    
            BoxLayout:
                id:t1bl1_2
                size_hint:(0.1, 0.15)
                Button:
                    id:t1bl2_1
                    text:"Past Performance" 
                    size_hint:(.5, 1)
                    on_press:root.hello_on()   
                          
                Button:
                    id:t1bl2_2
                    text: "Portfolio"
                    size_hint:(0.5,1) 
                    on_press:root.perf_on()
```

App screen shot

[image]

Comment: What is `MyLayout`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Its the name of main class which will be called by the build() function. the actual code starts like this '''<MyLayout> do_default_tab: False'''

Comment: I realize that, but what is the class definition for `MyLayout`? Is it a `FloatLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `GridLayout`, ...?

Comment: @JohnAnderson: its a GridLayout